# Urdu and Sindhi is Missing in System Support Langauges in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system, language-support

Urdu and Sindhi Language was available to change the System Language in Ubuntu 16 but in Ubuntu 20.04 Urdu and Sindhi languages are Missing. Can anyone help how to change System-wide language from English to Urdu or Sindhi. If any external language pack to install please guide, how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Those two languages have not been selectable in Ubuntu since Ubuntu 14.04, and the reason is that they both have very few translated strings while we nowadays apply a 5% threshold.

You may want to help revive respective translators team, with the goal to achieve at least 5% translation coverage.

[https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-sd](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-l10n-sd)

[https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-ur](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-l10n-ur)